# Using Intents from Flic Bluetooth Button to perform action on GPSLogger

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, android-gps

The Flic Bluetooth button ([flic.io](https://flic.io/)) app on Android allows you to fire an Intent from the app when you click the button. It looks to me as if this intent should just be a single line of code.

I would like to use this to sart logging on the [GPSLogger app](http://code.mendhak.com/gpslogger/), but at the moment can't get it to work.

GPSLogger says it can accept Intents in the format of:

**Action:** com.mendhak.gpslogger.GpsLoggingService

**Extra:** immediatestart:true (others below)

**Target:** Service

I have tried the following line in Flic, but with no success.
*action.com.mendhak.gpslogger.GpsLoggingService.extra.immediatestart:true.target:service*

also tried

*android.intent.action.com.mendhak.gpslogger.GpsLoggingService.extra.immediatestart:true.target:service*

Anybody have any ideas how to correctly specify this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to specify extra fields in the Flic app directly unfortunately. It's a planned feature however.

On the other hand it should be possible for you to write a simple app yourself that integrates with the Flic app to do exactly what you want. Just follow the tutorial at https://partners.flic.io/partners/developers/android-tutorial. You could also use the Tasker integration and do it through that.

Comment: Thanks Emil. I think Tasker might be the easiest, just to get a test system up and running to check functionality before investing time in coding an app. Is there a Tasker "plug-in" for flic, or does it work the other way around that there is a flic plug-in for Tasker?

Comment: Great, this all works with Tasker. For anyone else, Tasker has Flic as an "Event" plugin. With Tasker listening for the button click, I then set up the GPS logger as desired.
Thanks for the help.